# Are there any homogeneous prime ideals of $k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$ not containing $z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, projective-schemes

Let $R=k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)$. I would like to find the homogeneous prime ideals of $R$ not containing $z$. In other words, I would like to find the points of $D_+(z) \subset \operatorname{Proj} R$.

Any homogeneous prime ideal of $R$ corresponds to a homogeneous prime ideal $P \subset k[x,y,z]$ such that $(xz, yz, z^2) \subset P$. Since $(xz, yz, z^2)=(x,y,z)\cdot (z)$, then $P$ must contain $(x,y,z)$ or must contain $(z)$. In any case, $z \in P$.
So, there should be no homogeneous prime ideals of $R$ not containing $z$.

However, we also have
$$D_+(z) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(R_z)_0 \cong \operatorname{Spec} (k[z]_z)_0 \cong \operatorname{Spec} k.$$
So, $D_+(z)$ is a singleton.

---

Am I confused about something? Are there homogeneous prime ideals of $R$ not containing $z$? If so, what is it?

Comment: (as a side comment, it is the case more generally that, if $R$ is any commutative ring and $P$ is any prime ideal of $R$, then $P$ contains the nilradical of $R$: the set of all nilpotent elements of $R$. a converse in fact also holds; if $a\in R$ is contained in every prime ideal of $R$, then $a$ is nilpotent)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I see where I messed up. $R_z$ is not isomorphic to $k[z]_z$. $R_z = (k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2))_z = k[x,y,z]_z/(x,y,z^2) = 0$.

Comment: I now see you already realized your mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P\subset k[x,y,z]$ is a prime ideal containing $(xz,yz,z^2)$ then in particular $z\in P$, so indeed every homogeneous prime ideal of $R$ contains $z$. Your second line of reasoning fails because
$$R_z=\big(k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2)\big)_z=k[x,y,z]_z/(xz,yz,z^2)=0,$$
because $z^2$ is a unit in $k[x,y,z]_z$.

Answer (score 2):

$$R_z=(k[x,y,z]/(xz,yz,z^2))_z \cong k[x,y,z]_z/(xz,yz,z^2) = k[x,y,z]/(x,y,1) \cong 0.$$

So, $(R_z)_0 =0$ hence $D_+(z) = \varnothing$.